# osCommerce Authorize.net module gets response code as blank

Tags: curl, response, authorize.net, oscommerce

I have **osCommerce** site and integrated **Authorize.net** module in admin section. The payment module was working fine before and payment was done successfully.

But now suddenly i have noticed that customers face problem as they get following error when they click confirm button to confirm the order:

**"The server cannot connect to Authorize.net.  Please check your cURL and server settings."**

I tried to check in the response which i get in the response in **authorize.php** file, `before_process()` function. The response which i get is blank. No idea what is the problem.
Onto the server i have **cURL** enabled and correct path in admin section.
The **UserID** of the **Authorize.net** is also correctly set in admin section. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: helps?: http://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A131&pmv=print

Answer (score 0):

This may result from server changes that impact how the connection is executed as well.  If your server cannot generate a secure connection, Authnet will refuse it.